# Can't get keycloak to redirect to common login page when not authenticated

Tags: javascript, keycloak

Project is part of a larger site that uses a common login page and keycloak.  The keycloak script is part of a layout that is used by all pages.  When a user that is not authenticated arrives at page it correctly identifies it as 'not authenticated' an gives alert.  But it does not redirect to the page.

This is the script in the base layout used by all pages:

enter code here

```html
<script src="https://someplace.com/auth/js/keycloak.js"></script>    

<script>
  var keycloak = Keycloak({
    url: 'https://someplace.com/auth',
    realm: 'myrealm',
    clientId: 'myclientid'
  });

  keycloak.init().success(function(authenticated) {
    alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
  }).error(function() {
    alert('failed to initialize');
  });
</script>
```

It gives the correct alert 'not authenticated' but then does not redirect to the login page 'https://someplace.com/auth'

Comment: Ignore first </script> it is from poor copying.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the documentation [1]:

> By default to authenticate you need to call the login function. However, there are two options available to make the adapter automatically authenticate.

I think you're missing either a direct call to `keycloak.login()` or using `keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })`.

- [1] https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter